# Is there a relationship between RKHS and mixtures?

Tags: references, kernel-trick, mixture-distribution

Reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces (RKHS) (see [here](http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/~gretton/coursefiles/lecture4_introToRKHS.pdf) or [here](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/bhrnds/maschinelleslernen2016/maschinelleslernen09.pdf)) seem to involve conic combinations of "kernel functions" (my understanding is very crude). (See pp. 34-35 of [Behrends](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/bhrnds/maschinelleslernen2016/maschinelleslernen09.pdf), unfortunately the only version is in German; let me know if you find a better reference.)

Meanwhile, [mixtures of (continuous) probability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model#Multivariate_Gaussian_mixture_model) seem to involve convex combinations of their density functions.

**Question:** Is there any meaningful relationship between the theory of RKHS and mixture distributions, e.g. by taking probability densities as the kernel functions and then using linear combinations (while noting that every convex combination is also a linear combination)?

Pointers to references will suffice for answers -- I am aware that this question as written is vague, reflecting the vagueness of my idea.

Comment: This might be of interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_embedding_of_distributions. Also see review paper: [Muandet et al (2017). Kernel Mean Embedding of Distributions: A Review and Beyond](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.09522).

Comment: If it can clarify a bit: "taking probability densities as the kernel functions" - this does not make sense to me. Roughly, kernels could be interpreted as distances, they have to be symmetric. Even by defining something in the idea of the likelihood of A given B as a "distance/similarity measure", it will never be symmetric.
Also, RKHS define a Space where functions with given properties live. A mixture of distribution is a function and in no case a Space.
Your question is very interesting! I hope that some skilled people can bring more insights :)

Comment: @Eskapp I mean the space of all mixtures of density functions -- each mixture is an element of the space. You're right that arbitrary functions can't be kernels -- I guess I mean the procedure by which, for example, given the cosine function, one produces a kernel (see p.34 of Behrends, but it is in German). Given functions $f_i: X \to \mathbb{R}$, the associated kernel is $k: X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $k(x,x')=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x)f_i(x')$. (According to p. 35, _every_ kernel arises in this fashion.) Also I was wrong, kernels are only closed under conic, not linear, combinations.